# Problema con la etiqueta <audio>

Tags: javascript, html, script, audio, apk

Hace unos días subí mi problema, pero no se logró solucionar. Vuelvo a publicarlo ya que modifiqué un poco el código, pero sigue sin hacer lo que me gustaría, y es que, me encuentro desarollando una APK en HTML, pero necesito que cuando se pulse un botón de videollamada, simule una llamada de teléfono donde suena un tono, para rechazar o aceptar la llamada. Mi problema aquí es que el tono no suena, y no entiendo el porqué no lo hace (En navegadores sé que es por el protocolo del autoplay de la etiqueta audio, pero al pasarlo a APK tampoco suena.)

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    </head>
  <audio id="audio" src="assets/audio/tono.mp3">
  </audio>

<body id="llamada-fondo">
  <div id="title" class="d-flex text-center justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <img src="assets/img/circular.png" style="height: 10%; width: 30%;"><br>
  </div>
  <p style="color: white; text-align: center;">+34 6445467865</p>
  <div id="aceptar">
    <img id="aceptarllamada" src="assets/img/aceptar.png">
    <img id="denegarllamada" src="assets/img/denegar.png">
  </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio")
    audio.play();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentas que el audio debería sonar cuando se pulse un botón de videollamada.

Entonces debería ser en ese botón donde tienes que hacer el `.play()` no? y de este modo  no tendrás el problema del autoplay, algo así:

```
    </head>
  <audio id="audio" src="assets/audio/tono.mp3">
  </audio>

<body id="llamada-fondo">
  <div id="title" class="d-flex text-center justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <img src="assets/img/circular.png" style="height: 10%; width: 30%;"><br>
  </div>
  <p style="color: white; text-align: center;">+34 6445467865</p>
  <div id="aceptar">
    <img id="aceptarllamada" src="assets/img/aceptar.png">
    <img id="denegarllamada" src="assets/img/denegar.png">
  </div>
  </div>

  <div onclick="playAudio()">VIDEOLLAMADA</div>

  <script>
    function playAudio() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio")
        audio.play();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

También puedes controlar que no se muestren lo que tienes de aceptar / denegar hasta que no le hayas hecho click en el botón de VIDEOLLAMADA

Comment: Sí, en el botón de videollamada. El problema es que ese botón te redirige hasta esta otra página, ya que no se encuentran en la misma. Voy a probar ese método de todas formas. Muchisimas gracias por su ayuda.